# Need to create link to MVC Page from Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to create an email from which the user is supposed to click on it to get to a ASP.NET MVC page.
The controller name is Truck and the action is Edit.

I am not sure how to put this into a hyperlink such that the user can go to a page. 
Part of the issue is that in development, it says   localhost...  How can it be smart enough to get the path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from action and controller name you also need the hostname for this, as you said. You can get the hostname from `Request` object inside the ASP.NET MVC controller.

This is how I did this recently inside the controller to get the URL to a page, which I then included in emails. Works well for me both on localhost and hosting.

```
string url = Url.Action("action", "controller",
    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { id = id }),
    "http", Request.Url.Host);
```

`Url` is a `UrlHelper` that is accessible inside ASP.NET MVC controller.

Check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460297.aspx) for the specific `UrlHelper.Action()` method that I used. Seems that this is the only overload with the hostname parameter.